# Why a continuous map $f : M \to \mathbb{S}^n$ can be approximated by a smooth function?

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, differential-topology

Let $M \subset \mathbb{R}^N$ be a smooth manifold of dimension $m$ where $m<n$. Suppose $f : M \to \mathbb{S}^n$ is a continuous map. How can I prove that for every $\varepsilon >0$ I can find a smooth function $f_{\varepsilon}:M \to \mathbb{S}^n$ with $\sup\limits_{x \in M} \|f_{\varepsilon}-f\| < \varepsilon$?

I guess that might help the theory of "partition of unity" to construct such a $f_{\varepsilon}$ but I do not know it and I would like to prove the assertion without it.

I started from the case when $M$ is compact and I easily concluded using Stone-Weiestrass result. But how can I conclude in general case?

I will appreciate any help or suggestions.

Comment: Since you dislike partitions of unity (which is one of the most standard tools in differential topology) you should state in the question what tools are allowed. Incidentally, why do you dislike partitions of unity? It's hard to do anything with smooth manifolds without those.

Answer (score 0):

Using a smooth partition of unity, it suffices to consider the case that $M$ is $\Bbb R^n$ or even just the unit ball therein, and that the image of $M$ is contained in a hemisphere, say. Folding $f$ with a smooth kernel with tiny support (and normalizing) will then make $f$ smooth.

Comment: As I write in my question I would like to avoid partition of unity or smooth partition of unity. Might you review your answer, please? Equivalently is it possible to answer in a different way?